# How to send .apk file inside app using Bluetooth

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to send `.apk` file using Bluetooth inside the application?
(for example we launch app and then send `.apk` file using share icon inside app)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you want to send your own app's `.apk`, it's quite simple:

```java
// Get current ApplicationInfo to find .apk path
ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
String filePath = app.sourceDir;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// MIME of .apk is "application/vnd.android.package-archive".
// but Bluetooth does not accept this. Let's use "*/*" instead.
intent.setType("*/*");

// Only use Bluetooth to send .apk
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");

// Append file and send Intent
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share app"));
```

Comment: Hello ,The problem is that all database and cache file send too. I wnat to send just apk file without catch files.

Comment: No, the databases are not sent. Otherwise this would be a security hole in Android

Comment: hi, @ByteHamster . I tried to send from honor holly to Nexus 4 ,but this solution is not worked. It showing me as -content isn't supported .

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what to do about that. Looks like your Honor refuses to send the file type. Android itself also does not accept the apk mime type, so this solution itself is already a bit hacky

Comment: it sends the file as base.apk. can we change the name of file?

Comment: I don't know a simple way of doing that. You could copy the base.apk to a different location, rename it and send it afterwards.